# JSON decode php problems

Tags: php, jquery, json, post

I have index.php and getting problem with to decode the json array.. please help i am new to this..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#slider_price").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 1,
        values: [0, 100],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#app_min_price").text(ui.values[0] + "$");
            $("#app_max_price").text(ui.values[1] + "$");
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            var nr_total = getresults(ui.values[0], ui.values[1]);

            $("#results").text(nr_total);
        },
    });
    $("#app_min_price").text($("#slider_price").slider("values", 0) + "$");
    $("#app_max_price").text($("#slider_price").slider("values", 1) + "$");
});

function getresults(min_price, max_price) {
    var number_of_estates = 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'search_ajax.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'minprice': min_price,
            'maxprice': max_price
        },
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            number_of_estates = data;
        }
    });
    return number_of_estates;
}
```

And search_ajax.php

```
<?php
 require_once('includes/commonFunctions.php');
// take the estates from the table named "Estates"
if(isset($_POST['minprice']) && isset($_POST['maxprice']))
{
 $minprice  = filter_var($_POST['minprice'] , FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);  
 $maxprice  = filter_var($_POST['maxprice'] , FILTER_VALIDATE_INT); 
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE min_range >= $minprice AND max_range     <= $maxprice");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($rows);

}
?>
```

and the problem is i just want to print $rows in specific div "number_results".. how to decode that json array?

Comment: Please take the time to format your code correctly so it is at least readable. Normally I'd do it for you, but that's terrible.

Comment: please give me some idea about this how to encode the json array

Comment: you have to put 'return number_of_estates;' inside success

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Try using a JSON formatter / validator to see where you are going wrong. http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ It'll be how you are building the PHP array.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure about the data you are passing is in json format

i think it should be

```
'{"minprice": "min_price", "maxprice":"max_price"}'
```

Comment: Yes this is the min and max price range slider value.. Now it gives me only [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: @PanditAnkur i think i misinterpreted your question. Do you want number of rows to be shown on success or the rows themselves?

Comment: I need when slider values eg: 18 or 30. the output will show thoes records which are in between 18 to 30.

Comment: @PanditAnkur use `console.log(data)` in `success` and copy and paste the log as it is in the comment

Answer (score 0):

you cannot just return ajax returned value from a function since ajax is async...the function will already return `number_of_estates` ,   by the time ajax call completes.

use callback or just call a function and append your returned  text there

```
..
stop: function( event, ui ) {
  getresults(ui.values[0], ui.values[1]);
},
...

function getresults(min_price, max_price)
{ 
   var number_of_estates = 0;
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'search_ajax.php',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {'minprice': min_price, 'maxprice':max_price},
     async: false,
     success: function(data)
     {
        number_of_estates = data;
        $("#results").text(number_of_estates);
     }
  });
 }
```

however ajax is called each time the stop funnction occurs so be careful.

Comment: can u post your data you get inside success function.... try `console.log(data)` and check your developer tools

Comment: With my previous code it shows me [object Object],[object Object] on #results div.

Comment: did u try using `console.log()` .. alert will give you `[object Object]` for an object